# WKB method applied to boundary value problem where one side of the boundary is a turning point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

Consider the boundary-value problem
$$\varepsilon y''+x(x+3)^2y=0$$ for $a<x<b$

Find a first term WKB expansion of the solution in cases where,
$a=0,y(a)=0,b=1,y(b)=1$

I have constructed the solution in the following form
$$y\sim \frac1{\left( x \left( x+3 \right)^2 \right)^\frac14} \left( 2a_R\cos\left( \frac1{\varepsilon} \left( \frac25 x^\frac52 + 2x^\frac32 \right)-\frac{\pi}4\right) + b_R\cos\left( \frac1{\varepsilon} \left( \frac25 x^\frac52 + 2x^\frac32 \right)+\frac{\pi}4\right)\right) $$
There are two unknown constants in this equation as $a_R,b_R$. I can substitute $y(1)=1$ into the above equation to get one equation, but the boundary condition for $y(0)=0$ does not make sense since the solution is not defined at $0$ How do I deal with this case?

Comment: yes, I will update now.

Comment: Is there a deeper reason for $2a_R$? It seems that you need the difference of the basis solutions to get a limit at $x=0$. In what sense do you think this is an approximation? The values of the solution will oscillate wildly for $ε\to 0$.

Comment: This is a textbook exercise that I am trying on. The formula presented in the book has $2a_R&, actually it does not matter to use which symbol.